# How to change Preference text colour programmatically?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preference, preferencescreen

I'm adding preferences programmatically to my instance of PreferenceScreen (which I add to my PreferenceActivity). Everything works as expected except for the text colour, which always is white despite trying:

- To set the theme through manifest
- Set the theme programmatically
- A few other hacks that aren't notable

All I'm doing:

```
    PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);

    PreferenceCategory category = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    category.setTitle("Hello");

    screen.addPreference(category);

    CheckBoxPreference testPreference = new CheckBoxPreference(getApplicationContext());
    testPreference.setTitle("Test");
    category.addPreference(testPreference);

    setPreferenceScreen(screen);
```

I've set the theme to `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark` (which I don't want) and the text is legible, but this is what it looks like in any other case (I'm tapping it so you can see the text through the animation effect):
[image]

How would I go about making this text black?

Thanks!

Comment: What theme does your activity use (in the manifest)? If it's a theme you've defined, what Android theme does it extend?

Comment: I don't use a theme, and it seems no matter the theme I extend or modify, the textColor is always white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix, actually:

I had called `getApplicationContext()` in `CheckBoxPreference testPreference = new CheckBoxPreference(getApplicationContext());` which is not recommended for inflating views as it will almost always pass the wrong theme.

So, I changed `getApplicationContext()` to `this` and it loaded the text colour as what was described in the theme.